# How is red/black deployment strategy achieved?

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-delivery

I recently ran across this Netflix Blog article http://techblog.netflix.com/2013/08/deploying-netflix-api.html

They are talking about red/black deployment where they run the old and new code side by side and direct the production traffic to both of them. If something goes wrong they do a rollback.

How does the directing of the traffic work? and is it possible to adapt this strategy with e.g two Docker containers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of directing traffic is using [Weighted Routing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-weighted), as you can do in [AWS Route 53](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html).

Initially you have 100% traffic going to server(s) with old code. Then gradually you change that to have some traffic to server(s) with new code.

Also, as you can read in this [blog](http://rhelblog.redhat.com/2015/05/07/stop-gambling-with-upgrades-murphys-law-always-wins/#more-908), you can use Docker to achieve it:

> Even with the best testing, things can go wrong after deployment and a
>   rollback may be required.  Containers make this easy and we’ve brought
>   similar tools to the operating system with Project Atomic.  Red/Black
>   deployments can be done throughout the entire stack with Atomic and
>   **Docker**.

Answer (score 0):

I think they use Spinnaker to implement a red/black strategy.  https://spinnaker.io/docs/concepts/